# Bootstrap: How to fit images within carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel, responsive-images

I am using Bootstrap v3.3.5 carousel for this [web app](http://www2.montgomerycountymd.gov/DLCSupplierPortal/default.aspx), the images are fixed in dimensions (970x180), so I fixed the carousel dimensions as well.

However, when browsing this app from a smartphone, the images do not resize properly and only half of the image is visible.

Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the **.carousel .item** style. Remove the **width: 970px;** . Here you are setting a fixed width to image. Thats why it is not responsive.

I think the below code works for you.

```
.carousel .item {
    height: 180px;
    /* width: 970px; */
}
```

Comment: works, but images seems to be a little stretched out when browsing site from a smartphone, see here http://postimg.org/image/khm864ch5/